# MySQL Rows into Columns after operations

Tags: mysql

```
first..| last.. |category..|value..     |
+------+--------+----------+------------+
H-1    | I-15   |   A      |    190     |
H-1    | I-15   |   B      |    200     |
H-1    | I-15   |   D      |    1000    |
H-1    | I-4    |   A      |    20      |
H-1    | I-4    |   B      |    500     |
H-1    | I-4    |   D      |    10000   |
H-2    | I-0    |   A      |    79      |
H-2    | I-0    |   B      |    365     |
H-2    | I-0    |   D      |    1000    |
H-2    | I-7    |   A      |    450     |
H-2    | I-7    |   B      |    125     |
H-2    | I-7    |   D      |    10000   |
```

I want to get an output like:

```
first..|last....|D.........|A........|B........|A+B+D....|
H-1    | I-15   |   1000   | 190     | 200     | 1390    |
H-1    | I-4    |   10000  | 20      | 500     | 10520   |
H-2    | I-0    |   1000   | 79      | 365     | 1444    |
H-2    | I-7    |   10000  | 450     | 125     | 10575   |
```

I tried this:

```
select first, last, 
    max(if(category='D',(value), 0)) as 'D' ,
    max(if(category='A',(value), 0)) as 'A' ,
    max(if(category='B',(value), 0)) as 'B' ,
    (A+B+D) as 'ABD' 
FROM table 
GROUP BY last, first 
ORDER BY 'ABD' DESC ;
```

But it doesn't work.

**##### EDIT ########**

Suppose if I have to use something expression like (A+B)/D instead of (A+B+D) as ABD. How do I go about it?

**##### EDIT ########**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `CASE... WHEN... ELSE... END` instead of `IF` (which is not ANSI compliant AFAIK):

```
SELECT first, last, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN category = 'D' THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS `D`,
    MAX(CASE WHEN category = 'A' THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS `A`,
    MAX(CASE WHEN category = 'B' THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS `B`,
    SUM(value) AS `ABD`
FROM yourTable 
GROUP BY last, first
ORDER BY `ABD` DESC; -- guessing that AD is in fact ABD
```

Using `NULL` instead of `0` in the `ELSE` clauses make this work even with negative values.

Also, don't use `'` as delimiter for aliases, you have to use backticks ( ` ) if the alias contains special characters, nothing otherwise.

As an answer to your comment, the simplest would be to do a subquery:

```
SELECT first, last, `D`, `A`, `B`, (`A`+ `B`) / `D` as `ABD`
FROM (
    SELECT first, last, 
        MAX(CASE WHEN category = 'D' THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS `D`,
        MAX(CASE WHEN category = 'A' THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS `A`,
        MAX(CASE WHEN category = 'B' THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS `B`
    FROM yourTable 
    GROUP BY last, first
) AS x
ORDER BY `ABD` DESC;
```

Comment: Yes. Its supposed to be ABD not AD. Thanks

Comment: One More Question: Suppose if I have to use something expression like (A+B)/D instead of (A+B+D) as ABD. How do I go about it?

Comment: Not Working!. Error Code 1248: Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: Oops, missed the alias. Just add an arbitrary alias to the subquery (i.e. x here).

Answer (score 1):

This query also returns the same data that you seemed to expect.

```
select first, last, 
    max(if(category='D',(value), 0)) as D ,
    max(if(category='A',(value), 0)) as A ,
    max(if(category='B',(value), 0)) as B ,
    sum(value) as ABD 
FROM table
GROUP BY last, first 
ORDER BY ABD DESC ;
```

The only thing that is ambiguous was that you were ordering by AD. which doesn't exist.

[Link to SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ae1f2/5)

X.L.Ant, in another reply, has made a lot of good suggestions about how to improve your overall syntax.